# removing columns with a lot of zeros

Tags: r

I am refining my data frame to get rid of variables that are not useful. The first step I did was to remove columns having more than half of their rows as NA values, using this command:

```
limit <- nrow(mydata)/2
mydata <- mydata[, which(as.numeric(colSums(!is.na(mydata))) > limit)]
```

I am looking forward to make the same thing for zeros, but I could not find a function like "is.zero()", how can I do this?

The other thing that I am looking forward to do, is to remove any column that repeats any value more than "limit" times (it would be ideal if such a command exists!)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
mydata <- mydata[, which(as.numeric(colSums(mydata != 0)) > limit)]
```

As for removing columns that repeat any value more than "limit" times, you can use `table`, `any`, and `apply`:

```
mydata <- mydata[, which(apply(mydata, 2, function(col) !any(table(col) > limit)))]
```

Finally, note that both these cases the `which` is optional, and the `as.numeric` in your first case is unnecessary. You could simply do:

```
mydata <- mydata[, colSums(mydata != 0) > limit]
```

Answer (score 2):

To look for non-zeroes, simply replace `!is.na(mydata)` with `mydata != 0`.

To get the count of the most frequent element, you could use:

```
> mydata <- c(1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,1,3)
> sort(table(mydata), decreasing=T)[[1]]
[1] 5
```

To see the actual value that repeats the most:

```
> names(sort(table(mydata), decreasing=T)[1])
[1] "1"
```

If you don't care about preserving the value, you could use `max()` instead of `sort()`:

```
> max(table(mydata))
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks, my mind stopped working for some reason! 
Do you think there is a way to do the second part of this? I mean to remove any value that keeps on being repeated, instead of specifying "zero" or whatever?

Comment: Why would you sort the table instead of just using `max`? (Or, since you're testing if any go above a threshold, `any`?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson: `sort()` preserves the names, whereas `max()` doesn't (if I am not mistaken). Not that it matters here, but I though it nice to be able to find out the actual value that repeats the most.

Comment: @NPE but in this case he just wants to apply it to the columns, and remove those where it is repeated more than `limit` times.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, to know *which* value is repeated most. Also you could do `index.return=T` and access `$ix`. Alternatively, if you store `t <- table(mydata)` then you could do `t[t == max(t)]`.